# Ordering data from returned pool.apply_async

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am currently writing a steganography program. I currently have the majority of the things I want working. However I want to rebuild my message using multiple processes, this obviously means the bits returned from the processes need to be ordered. So currently I have:

---

Ok im home now I will put some actual code up.

```
def message_unhide(data):
    inp = cv.LoadImage(data[0]) #data[0] path to image
    steg = LSBSteg(inp)
    bin = steg.unhideBin()
    return bin

#code in main program underneath
count = 0
f = open(files[2], "wb") #files[2] = name of file to rebuild
fat = open("fat.txt", 'w+')
inp = cv.LoadImage(files[0][count]) # files[0] directory path of images
steg = LSBSteg(inp)
bin = steg.unhideBin()
fat.write(bin)
fat.close()
fat = open("fat.txt", 'rb')
num_files = fat.read() #amount of images message hidden across
fat.close()
count += 1
pool = Pool(5)
binary = []
''' Just something I was testing
for x in range(int(num_files)):
        binary.append(0)
    print (binary)
'''
while count <= int(num_files):
        data = [files[0][count], count]
        #f.write(pool.apply(message_unhide, args=(data, )))                #
        #binary[count - 1] = [pool.apply_async(message_unhide, (data, ))]  #
        #again just another few ways i was trying to overcome
        binary = [pool.apply_async(message_unhide, (data, ))]
        count += 1
pool.close()
pool.join()
bits = [b.get() for b in binary]
print(binary)

#for b in bits:
    #    f.write(b)
f.close()
```

This method just overwrites binary

```
binary = [pool.apply_async(message_unhide, (data, ))]
```

This method fills the entire binary, however I loose the .get()

```
binary[count - 1] = [pool.apply_async(message_unhide, (data, ))]
```

Sorry for sloppy coding I am certainly no expert.

Comment: Could your `while` loop be changed to a `for` loop over some iterable (e.g. a `range`)? If so, you could probably use `pool.map` to handle things for you automatically.

Comment: Otherwise, you probably want `binary.append(pool.apply_async(extract_bits, (data,)))` (note the added comma in the `apply_async` call).

Comment: I can't actually get my head around pool.map, every time and every way I use it, i just cant seem to get it working.

I can get this method working if I switch out 

   `binary = [pool.apply_async(message_unhide, (data, ))]`

with

   `f.write = pool.apply(message_unhide, (data, ))`

However this method does not speed anything up.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue has to do with overwriting `binary` in the loop. You only have one item in the list because you're throwing away the previous list and recreating it each time. Instead, you should use `append` to modify the existing list:

```
binary.append(pool.apply_async(message_unhide, (data, )))
```

But you might have a much nicer time if you use `pool.map` instead of rolling your own version. It expects an iterable yielding a single argument to pass to the function on each iteration, and it returns a list of the return values. The `map` call blocks until all the values are ready, so you don't need any other synchronization logic.

Here's an implementation using a generator expression to build the `data` argument items on the fly. You could simplify things and just pass `files[0]` to `map` if you rewrote `message_unhide` to accept the filename as its argument directly, without indexing a list (you never use the index, it seems):

```
# no loop this time
binary = pool.map(message_unhide, ([file, i] for i, file in enumerate(files[0])))
```

Comment: I did as you said and passed map the path of the files only,  this works fine however there is no noticeable speed change because as far as I can make out each process needs to complete first. However I could implement a loop that creates 5 async processes each with their own variable. Wait for those to complete then write the variables in order to the file. Keep doing this till every image is done.